# Making a container fit the width of its children

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to dynamically size a container to the width of its children when they're broken down into columns and rows. This can easily be achieved by writing a bunch of media queries and hard coding the width of the container, but I'm looking for a way to do it dynamically with CSS.

In this example id like `.container` to only be a multiple of the width of a fixed size `.item` (`200px`, `410px`, `620px`, `830px`, etc) and not include the empty space to the right.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #555;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did something like that before using JS. That only worked by having fixed item widths though, so not sure if that is what you want. I basically just calculated the max amount of elements that would fit in the width (including gaps etc.) and then set the width of the container to that amount * item width.

Comment: Why You Need It? It's only in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the width of items are fixed you can try like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,200px); /* same as width of items */
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px; /* move the padding here  */
}

.container {
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* take all the columns */
  background-color: #555;
  outline: 10px solid #555; /* use outline to cover the padding */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: inherit;
}

.item {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```